# why $(t^2, t^3)$ is not a submanifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R^{2}}$, $f(t)=(t^2, t^3)$, then the image of $f$ is not a submaniflod.

The definition of submanifold I learned is the following (some others call this regular submanifold):

A subset $S\subseteq M$ is called a submanifold of dimension $k\leq m$, if it has the following property: For every $p\in S$ there is a coordinate chart $(U, \varphi )$ around $p$, such that $\varphi (U\cap S)= \varphi (U)\cap\mathbb{R^k}$.

I know that if $F$ is an embedding, then image of F is a regular submanifold, but here f is not an embedding, so can not use this theorem.

And also, there is another answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1090680/1141262, but I don't understand how this answer use $D\alpha (0)=0$ to show that no chart $(U, \varphi )$ around $p$ exists, such that $\varphi (U\cap S)= \varphi (U)\cap\mathbb{R^k}$

Edited: I kind of understanding why from the above definition one can show submanifold is also locally a graph.

And I saw an answer, but I don't understand how the answer showed the image is not an submanifold. [Showing that $\tau(t) = (t^2, t^3)$ is not a submanifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3613599/showing-that-taut-t2-t3-is-not-a-submanifold/3613659#3613659) I think if a set is a graph of a smooth fucntion, then the set is a manifold, but I cannot understand why being a submanifold need locally to be a graph of a function as showed in the answer.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144431/discussion-on-question-by-diiiiiklllllll-why-t2-t3-is-not-a-submanifold); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.